# If $m,n$ are coprime positive integers and $m-n$ is odd, then $(m-n),(m+n),m,n,$ are coprime each other?

Tags: number-theory

If $m,n$ are coprime positive integers and $m-n$ is odd, then $(m-n),(m+n),m,n,$ are coprime each other?

How do I prove it?

Especially how do I prove $(m-n), (m+n)$ are coprime?

Comment: Not pairwise: $7$ and $3$ are coprime, but $7-3$ and $7+3$ aren't.

Comment: I've edited. Please have a look again. I've added a condition that $m-n$ is odd.

Comment: If a prime divides both $m-n$ and $m+n$, then it divides $2m$ and $2n$; so, assuming $m$ and $n$ coprime, the only prime that can divide $m-n$ and $m+n$ is $2$; but $m-n$ is odd, so this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$(m-n,n)=(m-n+n,n)=(m,n)$

$(m+n,n)=(m+n-n,n)=(m,n)$

If $d$ divides $m+n,m-n$

$d$ will divide  $m+n+(m-n)=2m$ and $m+n-(m-n)=2n$

$\implies d$ will divide $(2m,2n)=2(m,n)$

Comment: @julypraise, if $d$ divides $m-n,n; d$ will divide $m-n+n=m$  and if $D$ divides $m,n;D$ will divide $m-n$

Answer (score 0):

Since $(m,n)=1$ we have $mx+ny=1$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $(m-n)x+n(x+y)=1$ so $((m-n),n)=1$, and also $(m+n)x+(y-x)n=1$ so $((m+n),n)=1$

In similar calculation you can show $(m+n),m)=((m-n),m)=1$

lastly say $((m+n),(m-n))=d$ so $d\mid 2m$ and $d\mid 2n$ so $d\mid 2(m,n)$ so but $(m,n)=1$ so $d=1,2$

If $d\ne 1$ Then $2\mid m+n$ so $2\mid m$ and $2\mid n$ but $(m,n)=1$ so $2\mid 1$ which is contradiction so $d=1$ must!